# How to insert a column at the start of a txt file using awk?

Tags: linux, awk

How to insert a column at the start of a txt file running from 1 to 2059 which corresponds to the number of rows I have in my file using awk. I  know the command will be something like this:

**awk '{$1="  "}1' File**

Not sure what to put between the speech-marks 1-2059?

I also want to include a header in the header row so 1 should only go in the second row technically.

```
**ID**     Heading1
RQ1293939    -7.0494
RG293I32SJ   -903.6868
RQ19238983   -0899977
rq747585950   988349303
```

```
FID  **ID**     Heading1
1    RQ1293939    -7.0494
2    RG293I32SJ   -903.6868
3    RQ19238983   -0899977
4    rq747585950   988349303
```

So I need to insert the FID with 1 - 2059 running down the first column

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code. Please do start samples of input and expected output in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show does not work, it just replaces the first field (`$1`) with a space and prints the result. If you do not have empty lines try:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print "FID\t" $0; next} {print NR-1 "\t" $0}' File
```

Explanations:

- `NR` is the `awk` variable that counts the records (the lines, in our case), starting from 1. So `NR==1` is a condition that holds only when `awk` processes the first line. In this case the action block says to print `FID`, a tab (`\t`), the original line (`$0`), and then move to next line.
- The second action block is executed only if the first one has not been executed (due to the final `next` statement). It prints `NR-1`, that is the line number minus one, a tab, and the original line.

If you have empty lines and you want to skip them we will need a counter variable to keep track of the current non-empty line number:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print "FID\t" $0; next} NF==0 {print; next} {print ++cnt "\t" $0}' File
```

Explanations:

- `NF` is the `awk` variable that counts the fields in a record (the space-separated words, in our case). So `NF==0` is a condition that holds only on empty lines (or lines that contain only spaces). In this case the action block says to print the empty line and move to the next.
- The last action block is executed only if none of the two others have been executed (due to their final `next` statement). It increments the `cnt` variable, prints it, prints a tab, and prints the original line.
- Uninitialized `awk` variables (like `cnt` in our example) take value 0 when they are used for the first time as a number. `++cnt` increments variable `cnt` before its value is used by the `print` command. So the first time this block is executed `cnt` takes value 1 before being printed. Note that `cnt++` would increment after the printing.

Comment: Thank you Renaud. What does the  NR==1 mean and the %d\t?

Comment: See my edited answer for the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't really have a blank row between your header line and the rest of your data:

```
awk '{print (NR>1 ? NR-1 : "FID"), $0}' file
```

Use `awk -v OFS='\t' '...' file` if you want the output to be tab-separated or pipe it to `column -t` if you want it visually tabular.